# take a variable from database manipulate and insert other variable into same data base

Tags: php, mysql

i'm totally beginner at php . 
i try to take the highest index of player in my database add to it 1 
and then insert the new player information which the new index . 
here is my code :

```
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password']; 
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$con = mysqli_connect(...);

$asking = "SELECT MAX( playerNumber ) as playNum FROM Users";

$result = mysqli_query($con , $asking);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$numberOfPlayer = $row['playNum'] + 1;

$sql = 
"INSERT INTO Users VALUES ( " . $numberOfPlayer . ", " . $username . "," . $password ."," . $email . " , 0)";

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo $result2;
mysqli_close($con);
```

if i ask the query in phpmyadmin its give me the answear but if i try to do something it print me this eror :

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/u521040346/public_html/learning.php on line 8

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing mysql and mysqli. Use `mysqli_fetch_array`.
Anyway, you should use prepared statements, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.